# 4.2 Without cocoon, simple form or formtastic? Nested forms cookbook

Tags: forms, nested, cookbook

I struggle with nested forms.
There're three classes Recipe, Quantity and Ingredient:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :quantities
  has_many :ingredients, through: :quantities
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :quantities

class Quantity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingredient
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredient, :reject_if => :all_blank

class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :quantities
  has_many :recipes, :through => :quantities
```

Recipe Controller

```
def new
  @recipe = current_user.recipes.build
  @quantity = @recipe.quantities.build
end
def create
    @recipe = current_user.recipes.build(recipe_params)
    if @recipe.save
      redirect_to @recipe
    else
      render 'new'
    end
end
  private
    def recipe_params
      params.require(:recipe).permit(
        :name, 
        quantities_attributes: [:id, :amount, :ingredient_id],
      )
end
```

View for recipe#new

```
<%= form_for @recipe, html: {class: "form-horizontal"} do |f| %>
  <li class="control-group">
   <%= f.label :name, "Recipe Name", class: "control-label" %>
   <div class="controls"><%= f.text_field :name %></div>
  </li>
  <%= f.fields_for :quantities do |quantity| %>
    <%= render 'quantity_fields', f: quantity %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

_quantity_fields

```
<%= f.label :amount, "Amount:" %>
<%= f.text_field :amount %>
```

Here should follow a Select input with content from Ingredient and the POST request should insert the ingredient_id in the column of Quantity.

```
<%= f.select("ingredient_id", "ingredient_id", Ingredient.all.collect
  {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {include_blank: 'Choose'}) %>
```

getting

```
NoMethodError in Recipes#new

Showing C:/Sites/4.2/sample_app - Kopie/app/views/recipes/_quantity_fields.html.erb 
where line #6 raised:

undefined method `merge' for [["Sugar", 1], ["Butter", 2]]:Array
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= f.collection_select(:ingredient_id, Ingredient.all, :id, :name) %>
```

solved the select statement

but how can I create multiple quantities here?